# Select Sum em tabela com PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select

Eu tenho uma tabela com os seguintes campos: **data, hora e quantidade**. E eu preciso fazer um select sum disso.

Para entender melhor, eu tenho um formulário onde eu insiro uma data, após eu inserir, vou fazer uma consulta no banco e nela eu preciso retornar a informação de quantas 'qtd' tem em determinado horário da data escolhida.

Exemplo: eu preciso somar todo o campo 'qtd' na data **2017-06-07** às **11-00**, não permitir mais inserir valores nesse horário, se ultrapassar 150 (inteiro).

Essa imagem ilustra bem o que preciso fazer:

[image]

Eu estou usando o PHP/mysql, mas estou com dificuldade para montar essa lógica. O Select Sum faz esse tipo de operação? Qual é a melhor forma de fazer essa regra?

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: No caso, se houver um total de 140 e for inserido mais 20, deve ser permitido, pois só há 140 ou não deve ser permitido, pois 140+20 ultrapassa os 150?

Comment: Não deve, o máximo é 150 mesmo, pra ilustrar melhor: http://desenvolvimentopuro.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/tela.jpg

Comment: tem algum motivo/requisito de negócio para justificar a data estar separada da hora ou esse é um sistema legado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer a checagem:

```
$select = "SELECT hora,COALESCE(SUM(qtd), 0) FROM table WHERE data='2017-06-07' GROUP BY hora"; //No caso coloquei a hora e data que você utilizou no seu exemplo, mas teria que ser as váriaveis que você pegou do formulário.
$comando = mysqli_query($connect, $select); //$connect é o endereço do servidor.

$count = mysqli_num_rows($comando);
if ($count > 0)
{
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($comando))
    {
        printf ('Hora: %s Quantidade: %s \n', $row[0], $row[1]); //Só para fazer o teste, não necessário.
        if ($row[1] > 150)
        {
            echo "Indisponível.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Boa disponibilidade.";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Boa disponibilidade.";
}
```

Para realizar o update:

```
$select = "SELECT SUM(qtd) FROM table WHERE (data='2017-06-07' AND hora='11-00') GROUP BY hora";
$comando = mysqli_query($connect, $select);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($comando);
if ($row[0] + $quantidade > 150)
{
    echo "Não existem tantas vagas.";
}
else
{
    $update = "UPDATE table SET qtd=qtd + '$quantidade' WHERE data='2017-06-07' AND hora='11-00'";
    mysqli_query($connect, $update);
}
```

Comment: Exato, os horários já são definidos, por exemplo, das 11h até as 23h, e com intervalos de 1 hora. então, a partir da data, exemplo 2017-06-14, eu preciso saber se tem nas 11h alguma quantidade, e qual a quantidade que tem registrada, 12h idem e assim por diante –

Comment: Editei minha resposta, ve se lhe cabe agora.

Comment: No caso, nessa imagem http://desenvolvimentopuro.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/tela.jpg (que é como ficará)como eu faria para cada um dos horários? teria algum if?

Comment: Editei novamente, veja se está da maneira que você queria.

Comment: Boa, funcionou aqui...Agora, como faria para aparecer com os horários que apresentam 0 qtd?

Comment: Você teria que usar o `COALESCE`, para se caso o valor seja nulo, ele retorna 0. Editei minha resposta, vê se lhe cabe bem.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, é que no caso, como o loop vai ser com base no horário e data, vai ter data e hora que não vai estar cadastrado no banco, exemplo, se não tiver reservado na data 2017-05-15 às 11h, mesmo assim precisa aparecer a opção para reserva, e não terá nada no banco para selecionar, eu poderia fazer algum if nisso?

Comment: Sim, editei minha resposta, veja se está como você queria agora.

Comment: A única coisa que me deixou confuso, foi que os horários vão estar em formulário disponível, então 11h, 12h, 13h... 21h, 22h.. e nessa ordem, if de contagem fiquei um pouco confuso em como mesclar o loop com o formulário pré definido

Answer (score 3):

Vamos supor que sua tabela tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
create table quantidades (
    `id` int not null auto_increment,
    `data` date,
    `hora` time,
    `quantidade` int,
    primary key (id)
);
```

Considerando alguns valores na tabela:

```
insert into quantidades 
values (default, "2017-06-06", "13:00:00", 50),
       (default, "2017-06-06", "14:00:00", 60),
       (default, "2017-06-06", "15:00:00", 70),
       (default, "2017-06-06", "15:00:00", 30);
```

Ou seja, o sistema possui três horários cadastrados, cada qual com as quantidades 50, 60 e 100 (70+30), respectivamente.

Para selecionar os registros, exibindo a data, a hora e o total da quantidade de cada um basta fazer:

```
select `data`, `hora`, sum(`quantidade`) as `total` 
from quantidades 
group by `data`, `hora`;
```

Desta forma, serão retornados os três registros:

```
data       | hora     | total
-----------+----------+--------
2017-06-06 | 13:00:00 | 50
2017-06-06 | 14:00:00 | 60
2017-06-06 | 15:00:00 | 100
```

Para fazer a inserção de novos valores, garantindo que o total não exceda 150, basta fazer:

```
SET @data = "2017-06-06", @hora = "13:00:00", @quantidade = 60;
insert into quantidades (`data`, `hora`, `quantidade`)
select @data, @hora, @quantidade 
    where (
        select sum(`quantidade`) 
        from quantidades
        where `data` = @data and `hora` = @hora
    ) + @quantidade  <= 150;
```

A primeira linha:

```
SET @data = "2017-06-06", @hora = "13:00:00", @quantidade = 60;
```

Define as variáveis com os valores a serem inseridos no banco de dados. Esses valores provavelmente serão definidos com PHP. Algo como:

```
SET @data = "{$data}", @hora = "{$hora}", @quantidade = {$qnt};
```

Após, a instrução de `insert` padrão, porém, não seguida de `values`, mas sim de um `select`. Isso para que os valores a serem inseridos só serão passados do `select` para o `insert` se a condição do `select` for verdadeira. Neste caso, a condição é que a soma do total atual, mais a quantidade a ser inserida, deve ser menor ou igual a 150. Se for, os valores são passados para o `insert`, sendo inseridos no banco de dados. Caso contrário, se a soma entre o total atual mais a quantidade a ser inserida ultrapassar 150, o registro não é feito.

É importante salientar que, como é feito a verificação do total atual antes de inserir um novo registro, a data e hora já devem estar previamente cadastradas no banco, pois se não existirem, a condição do `select` não é satisfeita e o registro nunca será feito.

Então, por exemplo, ao inserir uma quantidade de 90 em 2017-06-06, 13:00:00

```
SET @data = "2017-06-06", @hora = "13:00:00", @quantidade = 90;
insert into quantidades (`data`, `hora`, `quantidade`)
select @data, @hora, @quantidade 
    where (
        select sum(`quantidade`) 
        from quantidades
        where `data` = @data and `hora` = @hora
    ) + @quantidade  <= 150;
```

O registro será feito, pois neste horário a quantidade total no banco é de 50 e está sendo inserido 90, totalizando 140, que não excede 150.

```
data       | hora     | total
-----------+----------+--------
2017-06-06 | 13:00:00 | 140
2017-06-06 | 14:00:00 | 60
2017-06-06 | 15:00:00 | 100
```

Porém, se tentar inserir a mesma quantidade no horário 15:00:00

```
SET @data = "2017-06-06", @hora = "15:00:00", @quantidade = 90;
insert into quantidades (`data`, `hora`, `quantidade`)
select @data, @hora, @quantidade 
    where (
        select sum(`quantidade`) 
        from quantidades
        where `data` = @data and `hora` = @hora
    ) + @quantidade  <= 150;
```

O registro não será feito, pois neste horário já há um total de 100 e 100+90 excede o limite de 150.

```
data       | hora     | total
-----------+----------+--------
2017-06-06 | 13:00:00 | 140
2017-06-06 | 14:00:00 | 60
2017-06-06 | 15:00:00 | 100
```

Um registro de uma quantidade de 50, ou menor, será feito como o esperado:

```
SET @data = "2017-06-06", @hora = "15:00:00", @quantidade = 50;
insert into quantidades (`data`, `hora`, `quantidade`)
select @data, @hora, @quantidade 
    where (
        select sum(`quantidade`) 
        from quantidades
        where `data` = @data and `hora` = @hora
    ) + @quantidade  <= 150;
```

Ficando na tabela:

```
data       | hora     | total
-----------+----------+--------
2017-06-06 | 13:00:00 | 140
2017-06-06 | 14:00:00 | 60
2017-06-06 | 15:00:00 | 150
```

> Se você estiver utilizando PDO, você pode verificar se o registro foi inserido ou não verificando o número de linhas afetadas pela instrução `insert`, através do método [`PDOStatement::rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php). Se retornar 1, o registro foi inserido, mas se 0, o registro não foi inserido pois o total excedia 150.

Comment: Muito boa sua lógica, mas como eu faria para fazer um where de data específica usando essa lógica? Seria melhor usar um while ou foreach para apresentar o resultado?

Comment: Como assim? Para exibir ou para inserir?

Comment: Para exibir as datas conforme na imagem que mostrei, de acordo com a data específica

Comment: No `select`, basta fazer `group by` apenas de `hora` e definir o `where` igual a data desejada, semelhante ao que está na resposta do Francisco.

Answer (score 2):

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c75434/1

**Criação de dados**

```
CREATE TABLE registro (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `data` date,
    `hora` time,
    `quantidade` int
);

INSERT INTO registro   
VALUES (null, "2017-06-06", "13:00:00", 20),
       (null, "2017-06-06", "14:00:00", 30),
       (null, "2017-06-06", "15:00:00", 90),
       (null, "2017-06-06", "15:00:00", 80),
       (null, "2017-06-05", "15:00:00", 100);
```

**Select agrupado por data e hora:**

`SELECT data, SUBSTRING(hora, 1, 5) AS hora_minuto, SUM(quantidade) AS soma_quantidade 
FROM registro 
GROUP BY data, hora_minuto`

**Select agrupado por data específica:**

`SELECT data, SUBSTRING(hora, 1, 5) AS hora_minuto, SUM(quantidade) AS soma_quantidade 
FROM registro 
WHERE data = '2017-06-06'
GROUP BY data, hora_minuto`

**Select por data e hora específica**

`SELECT data, SUBSTRING(hora, 1, 5) AS hora_minuto, SUM(quantidade) AS soma_quantidade 
FROM registro 
WHERE data = '2017-06-06'
GROUP BY data, hora_minuto 
HAVING hora_minuto = '15:00'`

**Quer saber qual horário tem mais quantidades (independente do dia) ?**

`SELECT SUBSTRING(hora, 1, 5) AS hora_minuto, SUM(quantidade) AS soma_quantidade 
FROM registro 
GROUP BY hora_minuto 
ORDER BY soma_quantidade DESC`

**Quer colocar a mensagem no própio retorno do select ? (não recomendo)**

`SELECT data, SUBSTRING(hora, 1, 5) AS hora_minuto, SUM(quantidade) AS soma_quantidade, IF(SUM(quantidade) > 150, 'Indisponível', 'Boa disponibilidade') AS descricao 
FROM registro 
GROUP BY data, hora_minuto`